# Wix Include file (.wxi) throws exception

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I am a beginner in Wix and we are trying to migrate from Installshield to Wix. However I am stuck with an error which I am unable to resolve. I have done my share of research online before posting this message and I am hoping to get some help from you experts in case someone had a similar problem and would be kind enough to point out the silly mistake I am making here.

Here is my Wix include file: properties.wxi

```
    <Include>

     <?define Language="1033"?>
     <?define Manufacturer="ABC Inc"?>
     <?define Name="TRIAL-MSI"?>
     <?define UpgradeCode="....GUID...."?>
     <?define Version="09.00.0021"?>
     <?define Comments="Contact: team@abc.com"?>
     <?define Description="TRIAL Application"?> 

     </Include>
```

And I am calling it in my code as follows:

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
        <?include properties.wxi ?> 

 <Product Id="*" 
                Name="${var.Name}"
                Language="${var.Language}" 
                Manufacturer="${var.Manufacturer}"
                UpgradeCode="${var.UpgradeCode}" 
                Version="${var.Version}" >

    <Package    Comments="${var.Contact}" 
                Description="${var.Description}" 
                InstallerVersion="200" 
                Keywords="Installer,MSI,Database" 
                Languages="${var.Language}" 
                Manufacturer="${var.Manufacturer}"
                Compressed="yes"
                Platform="x86" />
```

I am compiling my script on the command line:

```
         candle -arch x86 -I properties.wxi trial.wxs
```

I keep getting errors as follows:

error CNDL0048 : The document element name 'Include' is invalid.  A Windows Installer XML source file must use 'Wix' as the document element name.Source trace:

And I guess because Candle did not accept the include file, it throws exception for:

error CNDL0008 : The Product/@Language attribute's value, '${var.Language}', is not a legal integer value.

Could someone please help me with this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-I` flag to candle is used to specify a directory to search for include files:

> usage:  candle.exe [-?] [-nologo] [-out outputFile] sourceFile
>   [sourceFile ...] [@responseFile]
>
> -I    add to include search path

The Wix preprocessor will automatically look in the directory of the current source file for include files so there is no reason to specify the include file on the command line.  Your command line should only include the Wix source files:

```
candle -arch x86 trial.wxs
```

#### UPDATE:

Wix variables are inserted using `$(var.VARIABLENAME)`.  You have all of your variables surrounded with curly braces instead of parentheses.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I remove the -I flag then I get the other error still: error CNDL0008 : The Product/@Language attribute's value, '${var.Language}', is not a legal integer value.  Legal integer values are from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.
I don't think it's reading the values from properties.wxi

Comment: @HiteshSavla, see my update.  You're also missing the definition of `$(var.Contact)` from your sample.

Comment: I knew it was something silly that I was doing. Thanks a lot for helping me on this!.

Comment: For those of us using `.wixproj` files, you can add something to the include path using the IncludeSearchPaths property of the [Candle task](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/task_reference/candle.html).  For example: `<IncludeSearchPaths>dirs</IncludeSearchPaths>`

Answer (score 7):

I had this error when migrating `wxs` files to `wxi`

Setting the files `Build Action` property in Visual studio from `Compile` to `Content` fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, that was reason.

Comment: I my case it was, when I renamed in Visual Studio a wxs to a wxi accidently. It then is in the wrong place in the wixproj-file.
Just delete the wxi file and make sure it does no longer exist in the wixproj file. Then recreate it with the help of Visual-Studio.